# Copy Data from a table in one Database to another database

Tags: database, copy, oracle-sqldeveloper

Basically I have a two databases on SQL Developer.  I want to take the table data FOR A PARTICULAR RECORD from one database and copy it to another database's table.  What should be the query?  I don't want to use a restore to avoid data loss...  Any ideas?

I got a query from google:

> INSERT INTO **dbo**.ELLIPSE_PFPI.T_ANTENNE
>       (COLUMNS)
>       SELECT COLUMNS_IN_SAME_ORDER FROM **dbo**.ELLIPSE_PFPI.T_ANTENNE

What should be written in the query instead of **dbo**?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
I havent tested it but i think it works

```
   select * into [databaseTo].dbo.tablename from [databaseFrom].dbo.tablename
```

Comment: WHAT SHOULD BE WRITTEN INSTEAD OF dbo?